# Why does my Python code keep returning "Invalid mode." with proper input?

Tags: python

So I'm making a simple timer program to get better at Python since I've never really tried it before. With my limited knowledge of the language, I don't feel I'm qualified to diagnose this issue myself. I tried changing double quotes to single quotes around my "if mode ==" statements, but that didn't change anything. I keep getting "Invalid mode.", which is my error message for when it's not up or down.

Here is my code:

```
import time

seconds = 0
mode = "down"

def main():
    print("Timer v1.0 by Alexis Knox")
    time.sleep(1)
    seconds = int(input("Seconds to count: "))
    mode = str(input("Timer mode [up/down]: "))

    if mode != 'up':
        print("Invalid mode.")
        exit(0)
    if mode != 'down':
        print("Invalid mode.")
        exit(0)

    if seconds < 1:
        print("Invalid time.")
        exit(0)

    if mode == 'up':
        for x in range(seconds):
            x += 1
            print(str(x))
            time.sleep(1)

    if mode == 'down':
        y = seconds
        for y in range(seconds):
            y -= 1
            print(str(y))
            time.sleep(1)



# Ensure that we execute main
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Your logic is off. Even if you give `'up'` or `'down'` as inputs, it will check either `if mode != 'up'` **and** `if mode != 'down'`, which will always go into one of those branches.

Comment: Typically, you check the valid inputs using `if... elif...elif...` then deal with invalid input in a catch-all `else`

Comment: Also, casting the result of `input()` to a string here, `mode = str(input("Timer mode [up/down]: "))` is redundant. Since `input()` already returns a string, just do `mode = input("Timer mode [up/down]: ")`.

Comment: Thanks for the help :) Fixed it (and fixed redundant string cast on inputs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at what I have done here to your code this should fix the problem

```
if seconds < 1:
    print("Invalid time.")
    exit(0)

elif mode == 'up':
    for x in range(seconds):
        x += 1
        print(str(x))
        time.sleep(1)

elif mode == 'down':
    y = seconds
    for y in range(seconds):
        y -= 1
        print(str(y))
        time.sleep(1)
else:
    print("Invalid mode.")
    exit(0)
```

If you are running consecutive if statements as you were previously it is better to use the elif statement if they are relevant to each other as shown in my code. The else is also more efficient as this will do exactly what the first part of your previous code was doing except it will run the if and elif tests first. The else will basically catch anything that is not stated in the elif and if tests. How ever your output is probably not what you want it to be but that was not the issue

Answer (score 0):

If you input "up", the second `if` will be true since the mode is not "down". If you input "down", the first `if` will be true since the mode is not "up". Anything else, and the first `if` will go off since anything else is always not "up". I.e. in any case, one of the first two will go off before you ever get to the code that actually would handle things.